# Confusion over how to use explicit binding methods

Tags: javascript, object, binding, this

Not sure if anyone can help me with this issue but I am aware that one can use the bind, apply and call methods to make the this keyword within a function reference a particular object of your choosing.  However, I'm still a little confused because in certain instances when I expected a particular outcome I got another. Here is an example of an object I have:

```
var obj = {
    fullName: "John Doe",
    person: {
        sayHi: function() {
            console.log("This person's name is " + this.fullName)
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that calling the obj.person.sayHi() method will result in the person's name being undefined as the implicit object is person.

I am also aware that you can reference the correct object by calling the method using bind or call like so:

`obj.person.sayHi.call(obj)` or `obj.person.sayHi.bind(obj)()`

in order for the person's name to display. However, I also expected that one could attach the bind directly to the function expression inside of the object like so:

```
var obj = {
    fullName: "John Doe",
    person: {
        sayHi: function() {
            console.log("This person's name is " + this.fullName)
        }.bind(obj)
    }
}
```

and then call the function like so: `obj.person.sayHi()` and you would get the same result however in this instance the this keyword refers to the global object. However if I do the following:

```
let sayHi = function() {
    console.log("This person's name is " + this.fullName)
}

sayHi.bind(obj)();
```

then I get the desired result. Can anyone explain why the second approach is not a valid one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
var obj = {
    fullName: "Harry Potter",
    person: {
        sayHi: function() {
            console.log("This person's name is " + this.fullName)
        }.bind(obj) // obj is not defined here yet, obj is undefined
    }
}
```

Because `obj` is undefined when `bind` is called. `obj` is indeed defined when the declaration is over, but you have a kind of circular reference in your declaration of `obj` which most likely will have the value of `undefined` when `bind(obj)` is called.

Another way to see this explicitly is to do the following:

```js
var obj = {
    fullName: "Harry Potter",
    person: {
        sayHi: function() {
            console.log("This person's name is " + this.fullName)
        }.bind(obj) // obj is not defined here yet, obj is undefined
    },
    ref: obj
}
console.log(obj.ref); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Nikos thanks for the response. I think I'm on track now. I just wanted to know one more thing. If I do the following:

```
function dummy(fn) {return fn();}
var obj = {
    fullName: "Harry Potter",
    person: {
        sayHi: function() {
            dummy(function() {
                console.log("This person's name is " + this.fullName);
                console
            }.bind(obj))
        }
    }
}
```

Then calling the function `obj.person.sayHi()` will produce the desired effect. Is this somehow taking the function expression out of the object definition? Sorry I tried posting this as a comment however, I don't know how to get it into the correct formatting

Comment: using the `dummy` function delays the binding to `obj` for when the function is called, that is AFTER the actual `obj` declaration. Actually ANY METHOD that will bind to `obj` AFTER `obj` has been declared (and not while being declared) will work